# Pytest: Fixture variable not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, pytest, fixtures

I am new to pytest and I have written a test function with fixture but I am receiving an error that fixture variable is not found. Here is the code:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def func1(arg1,arg2):
     return arg1 + arg2

def test_func1(func1):
     assert func1== 4
```

When I run this file, I get the error `E       fixture arg1 not found`. If I define `arg1` and `arg2` globally and not pass them through function, this will work fine, but how can I pass an argument to fixture function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define arg1 and arg2 as fixtures themselves, then it should work. Do as follows:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def argX():
    # return 'enter definition of argX here'
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? How can I do that? arg1 is argument to function, why only arg1 and not arg2. Can you show how to be done in my case?

Comment: I based my answer only on the error message you copied, you should also do it for arg2.

Comment: But this is very inefficient, what would be the advantage of this method over just define arg1 and arg2 in another file and just import it to main module and never pass argument to fixture and just use arg1 and arg2 as global variables.

Comment: Well, I cannot see why it would be inefficient. Anything you use for your pytest tests should be fixtures, so defining this input as fixture makes sense to me.

Comment: Let me ask it in another way, does fixture support passing parameters to it without defining the parameter or argument as fixture itself. Like is there any way to make my original code to work besides global variable or defining arg1, arg2 as fixture?

Comment: No I do not think that would work. However, I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear how you want the arguments to be passed to the fixture. I can only guess that they are supposed to be parameters of your test function in which case you need to define them in `@pytest.mark.parametrize` and set them as `indirect` so that they are passed to `func1` fixture:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def func1(request):
     return request.param[0] + request.param[1]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('func1', [(1, 3)], indirect=True)
def test_func1(func1):
     assert func1 == 4
```